# Ruby Class 500 Error

Tags: mysql, ruby, class

Why is this not correct. What is wrong with it??

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "mysql"

class Game
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :urlName, :description, :hits, :categorys, :width, :height, :nilGame

  def load(id)
    #Load mysql
    begin
        # connect to the MySQL server
        con = Mysql.new('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database')
    rescue Mysql::Error => e
        puts "mysql error"
        ensure
        # disconnect from server
        con.close if con
    end
    rs = con.query("select * from games where id='#{id}' limit 1")
    rs.each_hash do |row|
      if row['id'].nil
        @nilGame = true
      else
            @id = id
            @name = row['name']
            @urlName = row['urlname']
            @description = row['description']
            @hits = row['hits']
            @categorys = row['categorys']
            @width = row['width']
            @height = row['height']
      end
    end
    con.close
  end
end
```

Comment: A 500 error should always produce a detailed error log entry.

Comment: The only error is that the 500 error page doesnt exists in the log :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ensure` is always called, no matter if an exception was raised or not. So you trying to query on a closed connection. So remove the con.close from ensure. You might want to `return` from here since it is not possible to query a nil object.
2. You probably need `require 'rubygems'` at the start, before `require 'mysql'` (if running as an independent file)
3. `if row['id'].nil` should be `if row['id'].nil?`

Comment: Thanks this stopped the error but it still returns nil for every column??

Comment: Try `puts row.inspect` as the first statement in the loop. You will get a better idea of what is returned. It might be that the columns are actually empty.

Comment: I created 3 instances of the class called id 1, 2 and 3 and it only puts row.inspect once and then it stopped. So it's not finishing the page??

Comment: That is because of `limit 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coding your own MySQL adapter, try ActiveRecord, DataMapper on any other ORM to make your life easier.